# How to implement CASE SELECT in WHERE clause

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables `T1` and `T2`

**Senario 1:**

Table T1 has a Column C1 with values terminal1, terminal2, terminal3

**Select C1 from T1**

Terminal1

Terminal2

Terminal3

Table T2 has a Column C2 with values terminal1, terminal2

**Select C2 from T2**

Terminal1

Terminal2

**Senario 2**

**Table T2 can sometimes be null**

**Select C2 from T2**

(null)

(null)

**My Output has to be**

**When Senario 1 Then**

Terminal1

Terminal2

**When Senario 2 Then**

Terminal1

Terminal2

Terminal3

i.e when table T1 and T2 have common values I want only the matching values

and

when Table T2 has null values then I want all the values
 from table T1

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you need is a left  outer join. Outer joins allow us to conditionally join tables.

This version of your query will return `STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION` for all the rows in `SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION` and matching values only of `SP_TEMP_LOOKUP.AIRPORT_TERMINAL`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION, B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL
FROM SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION A,
left outer join SP_TEMP_LOOKUP B
    on A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION = B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, there is no joining key between the two tables

Comment: yes,  your solution seems to give me all the values from only the left table, what i am trying to achieve is i only need intersecting or matching values if there are any And when all the all the values in one table are null then i want all the values from the other table

Comment: Hmmm. Please **edit your question** to show the result you expect from the sample data you've posted, and alternate sample data which lead to  different  result sets .

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs some proper formatting and elaborate more on the problem you are facing. I assume, you need a statement, which shows what values intersect, and if they do not - show only tables A. For that clause, you need to use inner joins and case structure. For example:

```
select
  ter."HEATHROW_TERMINAL",
  case
    when lok."HEATHROW_TERMINAL" is not null then
      'Terminal is in both tables'
    else
      'Terminalis only in main table'
  end terminal_state
from
  test_terminal_v ter,
  test_lookup_v lok
where
  ter."HEATHROW_TERMINAL" = lok."HEATHROW_TERMINAL"(+)
```

wheres, test_terminal_v (A) has values "5","4","2","3" and test_lookup_v (B) has "4","2","3".
Hope it helps.

---

After comments: there are several approaches. 1) You can use temporary tables. Create one and the code is:

```
begin
  insert into test_term_tmp
  select
    ter.terminal
  from
    test_terminal_v ter,
    test_lookup_v lok
  where
    ter.terminal = lok.terminal;

  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    insert into TEST_TERM_TMP
    select
      ter.terminal
    from
      test_terminal_v ter;
  end if;
  end;
```

or 2) use types, for example:

```
declare
  type t_term_tab is table of number index by binary_integer;
  l_term t_term_tab;
  l_i number := 1;
begin
  for l_rec1 in (
    select
      ter.terminal
    from
      test_terminal_v ter,
      test_lookup_v lok
    where
      ter.terminal = lok.terminal)
  loop
    l_term(l_i) := l_rec1.terminal;
    l_i := l_i + 1;
  end loop;

  if l_term.first is null then
    l_i := 1;
    for l_rec2 in (
      select
        ter.terminal
      from
        test_terminal_v ter)
    loop
      l_term(l_i) := l_rec2.terminal;
      l_i := l_i + 1;
    end loop;
  end if;
end;
```

Test the performance, based on your data. Hope it helps.

Comment: Here is the elaboration.

Comment: create table SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION(STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION varchar2);

insert into SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION values ('Heathrow Terminal 1');
insert into SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION values ('Heathrow Terminal 2');
insert into SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION values ('Heathrow Terminal 3');
insert into SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION values ('Heathrow Terminal 4');
insert into SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION values ('Heathrow Terminal 5');

Comment: create table SP_TEMP_LOOKUP (AIRPORT_TERMINAL varchar2);

insert into SP_TEMP_LOOKUP values ('Heathrow Terminal 1');
insert into SP_TEMP_LOOKUP values ('Heathrow Terminal 2');
insert into SP_TEMP_LOOKUP values ('Heathrow Terminal 3');
insert into SP_TEMP_LOOKUP values ('Heathrow Terminal 4');

Comment: select A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION,B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL from 
SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION A,SP_TEMP_LOOKUP B
where
case 
when A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION in B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL then B.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION -- select only matching values 
when B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL is null then a.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION end; --if B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL is null then return all the values from A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION

Comment: please copy paste the following in sql developer, i am not able to format it when adding comments, or i dont know how to do it

Comment: By elaborate, i meant what outcome do you seek, what do you expect to get with specific data. You do not need to post DDL and DML - we can build that in seconds. So with current data, can you post, lets say a table, with the outcome you seek?

Comment: If table A had values 1,2,3 and table b had values 2,3 the query should return values 2,3 but there is no joining key between the two tables

Comment: the same query must also do this, if table A had values 1,2,3 and Table B had all values to be NULL then the result should be values 1,2,3 i.e. all the values from Table A

Comment: And this result, outcome - where will you use it? Need to show in your application? Or will you use this result in other code?

Comment: this code is part of an automation process, there are about 40 million rows in the airport table and i want to extract only the customer who did a transaction in the 5 Terminals if specified in the look up table (matching data) and if look up table is null i still want all the data from the airport table which will go through more similar filters.

Comment: Updated the main post. Check it out.

Comment: the code looks to complex and running it in loop to check 40 million records is not an efficient way, is there any other simple way to do it using a where condition or case statements

Comment: Then use method 1). It cant get any simpler that this.

Comment: By the way, avoid "distinct" in statements - it wont improve your code performance - it could do the even the reverse - slow it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys, I think I found the answer

select distinct T1.C1, T2.C2

from T1 ,T2

where T2.C2=T1.C1 or T2.C2 is null;

**Where in my code it was**

select distinct A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION,B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL

from SP_RETAIL_TRANSACTION A,SP_TEMP_LOOKUP B

where B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL=A.STORE_TERMINAL_LOCATION or B.AIRPORT_TERMINAL is null;